# How would I prevent AsyncTask from being executed multiple times in onScroll event?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, infinite-scroll

I've got an AsyncTask which refreshes my listView in onPostExecute event and retrieves some data in doInBackground event. The problem is that my AsyncTask is being executed multiple times within onScroll event. How can I prevent it from doing that?
By the way, i'm trying to create an Inifinite Scroll in my app. Maybe i'm doing something wrong?
Here's my onScroll event:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
    try {
        itemNews = listAdapter.getData();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("itemNews is empty");
    }
    if(totalItemCount > 2) {
        artId = itemNews.get(firstVisibleItem).articleId;
    }
    if(firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
    {
        UpdateListAsyncTask updateListAsyncTask = new UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
        updateListAsyncTask.execute();
    }
```

And here's my AsyncTask:

```
public class UpdateListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public int currentArticleId;
    public Activity mActivity;
    RemoteData remoteData;
    public ListAdapterRegular listAdapter;
    UpdateListAsyncTask(int currentArticleId, Activity activity, ListAdapterRegular listAdapterRegular)
    {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.currentArticleId = currentArticleId;
        this.listAdapter = listAdapterRegular;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        remoteData = new RemoteData(mActivity, "News");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            remoteData.writeServerData("&from=" + currentArticleId);
            System.out.println("DoInBackground writeServerData");
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("UpdateListAsyncTask: doInBackground exception!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        List<News> dataList = Select.from(News.class).orderBy("date DESC").list();
        System.out.println("onPostExecuteInitiated");
        listAdapter.clear();
        listAdapter.addAll(dataList);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Any help and ideas are so much appreciated!
Update:
I had to redo my code, but it worth. I've done it according to link: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

Comment: what is the condition to Prevent ?

Comment: AsyncTask is being executed for like 10 times in average, untill user get's his finger off from screen.

Comment: what I meant is, "What is the condition to prevent it from firing"  onScroll will fire every time the user scrolls the screen. there must be some check in order to prevent your Async task being fired.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain ye, that's the question. Which if-else statement should I implement, so that AsyncTask would run only once? I've tried to check the status of asynctask and the problem is that it never gets "FINISHED" status. It's always "RUNNING".

Comment: The status should have changed to FINISHED if your onPostExecute in your Async task was completed. Is something being done there that is taking too much time ?

Comment: @AnudeepBulla here what happens in doInBackground method: it takes data from remote server and write it into mobile database using Sugar ORM. and in onPostExecute method it gets data from mobile database, attaches it into listview adapter and notifies the adapter that data has been changed. Should work..in theory :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this

```
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
    try {
        itemNews = listAdapter.getData();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("itemNews is empty");
    }

    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
    }

    if(totalItemCount > 2) {
        artId = itemNews.get(firstVisibleItem).articleId;
    }

    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if(loading && totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
    }

    if(!loading && firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
    {
        loading = true;
        UpdateListAsyncTask updateListAsyncTask = new UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
        updateListAsyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

PS When I implemented the infinite scroll I used this as an example https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

Comment: what are currentPage and startingPageIndex variables for? and how could totalItemCount be less then previousTotalItemCount?

Comment: @Rishka Sorry, I should have left the comments. In your implementation currentPage and startingPageIndex are not used. I removed them

Comment: Thank you a lot, @schopy, thanks to your link i've managed to make it work and work perfectly=) I've had to redo all my code, but it worth it))

Answer (score 1):

There can be other improvements to your approach, but without any of them, if all you want is multiple async tasks to not run, why not try this ?

**Change**

```
if(firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
{
    UpdateListAsyncTask updateListAsyncTask = new UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
    updateListAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

**To**

```
if(firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
{
    if(mUpdateListAsyncTask != null && (mUpdateListAsyncTask.getStatus == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING|| mUpdateListAsyncTask.getStatus ==AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
         return;
     } else {
         mUpdateListAsyncTask = new UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
         updateListAsyncTask.execute();
     }
 }
```

Basically, just skip creating a new async task and running it if the status if RUNNING or PENDING. Should work.

Comment: I've triend to implement check for status but once AsyncTask was executed, it never gets to "FINISHED" status for some reasos((

Comment: That is weird. In that case, just invert all conditional statements. Check for status PENDING and RUNNING, and just return, and if that is not the case, create a new one.

Comment: it solves the problem - asynctask don't execute for than once...but my list doesn't refresh=( Would you be so kind and check my AsyncTask too?

Comment: Can you print the logs ? Check if your onPostExec is executed, and what is the count of the dataList ?

Comment: It looks like dataList count is always the same...maybe some problems with database, i'm trying to figer it out

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to execute the last task so I would make `UpdateListAsyncTask updateListAsyncTask` an atribute.

now change this:

```
if(firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
{
    UpdateListAsyncTask updateListAsyncTask = new UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
    updateListAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

to this:

```
if(firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
{
    try{
        updateListAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }catch(Exception ex){}

    updateListAsyncTask = new     UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
    updateListAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private UpdateListAsyncTask updateListAsyncTask = null;

...
if(firstVisibleItem > ((previousTotal)/2))
    {
//Create just if not exist or if it's finished
    if (updateListAsyncTask == null || updateListAsyncTask.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) {
        updateListAsyncTask = new UpdateListAsyncTask(artId, mActivity, listAdapter);
    }

//Start only if it's not already running
    if (updateListAsyncTask.getStatus() == Status.PENDING) {
        updateListAsyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```